# SharedPreferences does not work correctly when using Notification to start the Activity

Tags: android, notifications, sharedpreferences

I'm having a problem when using Notification to start an Activity.

I store the value of Boolean parameter *X* when it changes.
The code is like below

```
private void storePrefs() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
        edit.putString(PREF_init, X.toString());
        edit.commit();
}
```

And when I use the Notification to start the Activity, it always returns "true" no matter what I stored.
The restore code is like this.

```
private void restorePrefs() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREF, 0);     
    String pref_init = settings.getString(PREF_init, "");
    if(!pref_init.equals("")) {
        X = Boolean.parseBoolean(pref_init);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the value of `PREF_init` key *just before using it*. I bet it's different. Either this or the name `PREF` is different. Use the default shared preferences btw except if you have a reason not to.

And yes - use a boolean for this !

Comment: I replace getSharedPreferences into getdefaultsharedpreferences and it works correctly now. Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using putBoolean()/getBoolean() instead of converting it to and from string.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But it still acts the same.